# How to fire event from ComboBox inside StackPanel in WPF and MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have ComboBox inside StackPanel. I am using MVVM and try to bind 'GotFocus' event Command to Command in ViewModel but when I Click on 'ComboBox', it don't work (It don't call Command in ViewModel) but if I move that 'ComboBox' out of 'StackPanel' it's working properly.

```
How can I fire event from 'CombBox' inside 'StackPanel' in MVVM?

  <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6">
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
          <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=GotFocusCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
  </StackPanel>

ViewModel's code is:

public ViewModelCommand GotFocusCommand { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is ViewModelCommand? Is this some of your custom classes? I would first try to bind a normal handler for GotFocus event on the Combobox, and see if it is called anyway. For example, if your page have only that one Combobox it may be selected before you assign DataContext, and event is not fired then.

Comment: In my viewModel there is a command which I bind with combobox EventToCommand, that is                                                              public ICommand GotFocusCommand                                     {
            get
            {
                return _gotFocusCommand ??
                    (_gotFocusCommand = new RelayCommand(MethodNameToBeFired, () => _isLoaded));
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

////Change your tag from EventToCommand to InvokeCommandAction

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6">
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
      <cmd:InvokeCommandAction="{Binding Path=GotFocusCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

////Then, I use my commands this way in my view model:

```
  private ICommand _GotFocusCommand;
    public ICommand GotFocusCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_GotFocusCommand == null)
            {
                _GotFocusCommand =
                    new RelayCommand(
                        param => GotFocusCommand_Executed(),
                        GotFocusCommand_CanExecute
                     );
            }

            return _GotFocusCommand;
        }
    }
```

////RelayCommandClass.cs:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
private Action _handler;
public RelayCommand(Action handler)
{
    _handler = handler;
}

private bool _isEnabled;
public bool IsEnabled
{
    get { return _isEnabled; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _isEnabled)
        {
            _isEnabled = value;
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            {
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return IsEnabled;
}

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _handler();
}
}
```

////Finally, you can create an event in your view model:

```
private void GotFocusCommand_Executed()
    {
        //DoSomething here
    }

private bool GotFocusCommand_CanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I am using 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command', so I only able to access 'EventToCommand'. Kindly let me 'InvokeCommandAction' belongs from which namespace. Thanks

Comment: xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" which comes from Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll